# How to get request size using RestKit

Tags: ios, restkit

I am developping an iOS app that uses RestKit to make requests to my REST API. Since there are cases that could use a lot of data, I want to limit the data usage of my app. I could calculate the length of the data I post and the length of the data I receive, but this does not give me the overhead of these requests.

Is there a way to have the total amount of data used by my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function which is keeping track of that right now but you can do that yourself in your app.

I recommend creating a singleton RestKit Interface class which does all of your network operations.
Then all you have to do is before each request, you can use this call in RK

```
NSURLRequest *request = [self requestWithObject:object method:method path:path parameters:parameters];
```

Keep a static param in this class called myUsageStat and before making the request, increment myUsageStat by the size of request.HTTPBody (+ headers and url size if you care about those as well)

you will have to do the same for responses.

Hth